# My cron job doesn't run

Tags: cron

1. I set up to run notify-send every minute,

   ```
   $ crontab -l
   1 * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send -t 0 "hello"
   ```

   Why does it not work? Do I need to restart OS after editing the crontab file?
2. Does the following mean that `cron` is running?

   ```
   $ ps aux | grep -i cron
   root      1038  0.0  0.0  23660  2420 ?        Ss   Apr20   0:00 cron
   ```
3. Can I specify a more frequent schedule, such as 30 seconds? Can the
   time be specified as decimals?

   ```
   0.5 * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send -t 0 "hello"
   ```

Comment: Related: [Run a cron job every minute, meaning of syntax](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86123/run-a-cron-job-every-minute-meaning-of-syntax)

Comment: Also related: [Cron running job every 15 seconds](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/cron-running-job-every-15-seconds)

Comment: Your current cron job doesn't run every minute; it runs at one minute after the hour (00:01, 01:01, 02:01, etc.). But the real problem is that `notify-send` won't work from the restricted environment in which cron jobs run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have the wrong syntax for running a job every minute:

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send -t 0 "hello"
```

The `1` in the first field means that the job runs only at 1 minute after each hour. Change it from `1` to `*`:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send -t 0 "hello"
```

The second problem is that cron jobs run in a very limited environment. On my system (Linux Mint), the only environment variables that are set are `$HOME`, `$LOGNAME`, `$PATH`, `$LANG`, `$SHELL`, and `$PWD` -- and `$PATH` is normally set to `"/usr/bin/:/bin"`.

At the very least, the lack of a setting for `$DISPLAY` means that `notify-send` can't display anything.

A quick experiment with:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send "hello from crontab"
```

resulted in this error:

```
(notify-send:18831): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

(I'm running the Gnome desktop.)

In another experiment, I copied my entire interactive environment into a script, then edited the script so it sets all the environment variables explicitly and invokes `notify-send`. That actually works; I'm now getting a pop-up "hello from crontab" message every minute.

I'm certain that I don't need *all* my interactive environment for this to work, but I don't know exactly which environment variables are needed or what their values need to be. It's very likely that some of the needed variables are set when the current login session is started, and that they'll change if I logout and login again. It's also very likely that the details will vary depending on which desktop environment you're using.

This is not a complete solution, but it should give you a starting point -- and perhaps someone else can add the relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cron` job almost certainly *is* running. However, you cannot (easily) interact with your GUI from `cron` so unfortunately `notify-send` will fail.

You can prove whether or not your `cron` job is running by modifying the `crontab` line as follows

```
1 * * * * ( date; notify-send /usr/bin/notify-send -t 0 "hello"; echo ) >>cron.log 2>&1
```

This will write the date and any output from the `notify-send` command to a log file called `cron.log` in your home directory.

Please note, however, that as copied from your question this will only run at the first minute of every hour (`1 * * * *`). To run every minute you would need to use `* * * * *` ("every minute" instead of "1st minute"). Kudos to @KeithThompson for pointing this out.

The granularity of `cron` is one minute. If you need to run a job more frequently than this you may want to consider either a standalone daemon, or two lines in `cron` one of which is preceded by `sleep 30`.

Comment: how do you schedule notify in crontab? My eventual goal is to schedule backup by rsync in crontab, and get a desktop notification 5 mins before backup. How can I do that?

Comment: @Tim that's sufficiently different to this question that I'd recommend you ask it separately. (It's hard, though.)

Comment: Then how can you schedule notification in cron?

Comment: This makes the same mistake as the original question: the `1` in the first field means it runs once an hour, at NN:01, not once every minute.

Comment: @Keith ah yes, well spotted. +1 to you, thank you. I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$ crontab -l
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send -t 0 "hello"
```

try this if you want to run your `cron` every minute.

Comment: Please would you explain why you think this is any different to the problematic crontab the OP has posted.

Comment: @roaima: It's different in that it actually runs every minute, rather than one minute after each hour as the cron job in the question would. `* * * * *` would also work; the `/1` is not needed. But `notify-send` still won't work in that environment.